# paypal with ActiveMerchant

Tags: paypal, activemerchant

Hi
I want to implement credit() method using activemerchant.
I am using PaypalExpress Gateway for that.
When I show the Rdoc for Activemerchant, I have seen the parameters used in credit method credit(money,identification,options)
I want to know what is the meaning of each parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Money: is the amount in cents

Options: can be found in Class: ActiveMerchant::Billing::Gateway http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/frames